# How does a request URL "HelloWorld" instantiate a HelloWorldController object in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm finding [this documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller) very confusing.

After creating a file

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc; 

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers 
{ 
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller 
    { 
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/ 

        public string Index() 
        { 
            return "This is my <b>default</b> action..."; 
        } 

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome() 
        { 
            return "This is the Welcome action method..."; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

in the Controllers folder of my ASP.NET MVC project, I  can make a URL request to the child page `HelloWorld` of my site and apparently an instance of a `HelloWorldController` object is created and its method `Index()` invoked. How exactly that happens is a mystery to me. The documentation has 1 sentence that simply says

> The first part of the URL determines the controller class to execute.
>   So /HelloWorld maps  to the HelloWorldController class.

but I don't understand how that happens. There must be somewhere else in the MVC  source files that takes a URL request for a subpage and appends it with "Controller" and looks for a class with the same name derived from the `Controller` class. Where does that magic happen? Also, how does that translate into runtime, since at runtime the names of classes in the source code are extinct/irrelevant? Or am I totally confused about everything?

Comment: It is a naming convention, you can override all this, but in asp.net.mvc a lot of the logic by default it is done by naming conventions. So since you are requesting a page called "HelloWorld", it will look for a HelloWorldController to instantiate.

Comment: You pretty much explained the high level process in your question. I'm not sure which specific source files to look in to find that bit of code but I'm sure you can find it if you really want. Obviously the class names are still known at runtime, think about stack traces. That information gets included in the binary.

Comment: Long time ago when I started working with MVC, I found this video by Scott Hanselman very clarifying => http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman

Comment: This article about routing can be useful for understanding routing in mvc => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Here is another article which explains the routing module for MVC. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping a request from the **routing system** to **a controller** is the responsibility of **[DefaultControllerFactory](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs)** class.

`DefaultControllerFactory` follows the [convention-over-configuration pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). The factory looks for controller which meets the following critera -

- The class must be public
- The class must be concrete
- The class must not take generic parameter
- The name of the class must end with Controller
- The class must implement the IController interface

If you want `HelloWorld` request map to `HelloWorldJonDoe` controller, you can create `ControllerFactory` by overriding `DefaultControllerFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't totally confused about it. Routing takes a bit of learning for MVC. Take a look in your project for `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`. In this file you will see where the default route is created for MVC.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

The URL section shows what the URL passed in will look like and the defaults show what will be put in if you do not fill in all the sections in the URL. This is how it maps the URL segment to controller. It does essentially append `Controller` to `HelloWorld` to get the proper class, but this is why it knows that `HelloWorld` is the controller in the first place.

I found this link helpful if you need more information on how to work with routes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Routing system just extracts values from the URL and pass them along the request pipeline. It doesn't know anything about controllers and actions. Instead, controller factory is responsible for handling the incoming request and mapping it to specific controller. I agree that the question is vague.

Comment: True, I didn't mean to imply that the routes figured out the controller class, just that the route defines what will be used for the mapping of data that the factory needs.